# Windows 7 Windows Media Center controlling updates

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-media-center

Windows Media Center on Windows 7 likes to keep itself up to date.  The problem is that it even wakes the computer from sleep mode in order to do it.  I sleep in the same room as the computer so I don't want it turning itself on in the middle of the night.  How so I specify that I only want it to update if the computer is actually on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://www.avsoft.nl/Tools/guidedltime/ it is a guide time that you can set to auto update the mce guide. Set it for when the computer is normally online.

Comment: On a related note, is it just the internet tv guide that it looks to update?  I'm in the UK and there is no internet TV service here so if that's the case then I could just disable updating altogether.

Comment: Yes, if you are not using MCE for TV than there is no reason for it to auto update.